# How to release different version's binary to pypi.org?

Tags: python, pypi

Got a problem here, if I'm using cython in my package, the compiled `.pyd` file differents from different python version, for example, .pyd file compiled under python3.7 will not be recognized by python3.8 . If I'd like to release my package to pypi , let's say for example the version number be `1.0.0`, how can I upload the package, let different version's python running the same command `pip install package==1.0.0` and get its own version's compiled file separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically there are two kinds of archive formats that you should publish. They are called "*distribution packages*" and we have:

- "*source distributions*" ("*sdist*" for short);
- and "*built distributions*" (or "*binary distributions*", "*bdist*" for short).

Sdists should not contain any platform specific components, in your case should not contain the compiled Cython code.

And bdists on the other hand are meant to contain compiled code (compiled Cython files for example) and thus are allowed to be platform specific.

Nowadays the most common and the only recommended kind of bdist format is "*wheel*".

So you should distribute (publish on *PyPI*) the *sdist* of your project, and if possible try to build as many platform specific *wheels* as you can.

See for example the [distribution packages for *pandas v2.2.1*](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/1.2.1/#files), there is exactly one *sdist* and many different *wheels* that cover a wide range of:

- Python interpreter versions
- operating system
- CPU bitness
- etc.

Notice how all the file names are different. *PyPI* does not allow uploading files with the exact same name. *pip* (and other packaging-related tools) are able to interpret those file names and make educated guesses about what their contents are, and thus pick the right distributions to download and install.

Comment: The important part being that platform-specific wheels will have different names, and PyPI accepts multiple uploads for the same version if the files have different names.